SMB mount won't follow NTFS symlinks or junctions
I have 2 problems, one old, one new.
I have a linux nas, that I also run a web server on. To share files from my main computer on the internet, I mount a specific folder located on my windows machine to linux. E.g.
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=~/.smbcredentials //192.168.0.2/c$/users/martixy/srv/ /mnt/http_mount/nas/main
Then I drop anything I want shared there.
Problem 1
The new problem, which used to not be there (I think it cropped up after the latest apt upgrade, but I'm not sure) is that the junctions (i.e. directory symlinks) I used to have no longer work, giving me a permission denied error.
When I manually navigate to that location in ubuntu's file explorer, it asks me for a password, and then the junction works in the explorer. But I already supply the password when I mount the share (I also tried -o username=martixy,password=xxx which did nothing).
Problem 2
It won't follow symlinks properly. The file explorer tells me that the contents of the link are invalid - e.g. /??/c:/file.jpg.
I think that also used to work, but I haven't used it often, and may be misremembering.
